# Rviz doesn't visualize any meshes

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, recently I installed hydro in a computer with fuerte while mantaining this latter version. I had several problems, one solved here:

"answers.ros.org/question/44996/cannot-run-roscore-due-to-error-in-rosversion/"

and another with rviz showing this message:

[ WARN] [1388656039.856059873]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/glsl120/nogp/box.frag Cannot compile GLSL

The latter was solved after actualizing to rviz 1.10.10, but now it doesn't display any meshes: not collada meshes sent through a marker not even a point cloud when is displayed in style "cubes" (though it properly represent the cloud in any of the other sytles).

The packages and meshes I am using works fine in other computers where I also installed hydro jointly with a fuerte version (though I never got this warn from rviz previously).

I don't know what more to do, I uninstalled fuerte and reinstalled hydro with no improvements. Any one has idea about where this fail may come from? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115421/rviz-doesn%27t-visualize-any-meshes/) by [ercarrion43](https://answers.ros.org/users/2217/ercarrion43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to make sure you source Hydro. Go to your terminal, use the command `cd && nano .bashrc` to enter the file and add the line `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` at the end.  Hit ctrl+X to exit and hit y to save changes.  See if this helps at all.

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0